# DrawerLayout loses state on orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I'm toggling a DrawerLayout's state from a button's onClick, and disabling its swipe.
That works OK, but when the Activity changes its orientation, the Drawer doesn't retain its state; **if it was opened, it will get closed**. It even happens adding `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` .

Code in my Activity:

```
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private int drawerLayoutGravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    disableDrawer();

    View btnOpenDrawer = findViewById(R.id.btn_open_drawer);
    btnOpenDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggleDrawerState();
        }
    });
}

private void toggleDrawerState() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(drawerLayoutGravity)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(drawerLayoutGravity);
    } else {
        drawer.openDrawer(drawerLayoutGravity);
    }
}

/**
 * doesn't let the user swipe to open the drawer
 */
private void disableDrawer() {
    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}
```

A possible solution is that I re open the DrawerLayout on the Activity's `onConfigurationChanged`, but I need to **avoid showing the DrawerLayout re opening when the configuration changes**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting a closed lock mode on the drawer to disable swiping. Even though you've disabled `Activity` re-creation, the orientation change will trigger a layout event on your `View`s, and the `DrawerLayout` will set the drawer state according to the lock mode when laying itself out.

You need to update the lock mode whenever you programmatically open/close the drawer.

```
private void toggleDrawerState() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(drawerLayoutGravity)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(drawerLayoutGravity);
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    } else {
        drawer.openDrawer(drawerLayoutGravity);
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: Though what you say does make sense, in this case it shouldn't be the issue since I'm using `:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`, thus the onCreate isn't called on an orientation change. Thanks!

Comment: It's still triggering a layout event on your `View`s, and with a lock mode set, `DrawerLayout` will set the drawer state according to that. I'll phrase my answer a little better.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. My logic is a little off. Gimme a minute. I'll fix the answer.